# How to show a pointer on specific table with css and Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[EDIT]
Excuse me for asking this hugely stupid question. Please don't waste your time reading it. Just help closing it by voting for a close.

In my (Bootstrap using) website I've got a couple tables, of which on one I want to show a pointer on hover. So to show the pointer I copied the following code from [this page](http://tech.pro/q/1/twitter-bootstrap-css-table-row-cursor-pointer):

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover > td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This works perfectly well. I now want to show the pointer ONLY on tables which are of a specific class. So I gave a class to the table I want to show the pointer on:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="show-pointer-form">
```

and I added that class to the css:

```
.show-pointer-form .table-hover tbody tr:hover > td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Unfortunately, that it doesn't show the pointer at all anymore. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: can you post ur html or fiddle it?

Comment: Nevermind, I've been hugely stupid. I changed the class on a wrong table/form. Excuse me. This question can be closed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something which turned out to be pure stupidity.

Comment: You know there is a "delete" action for your own questions, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r43Ldxa0/) to a thing i made.

You can just add a class to a table and then use that class to get a pointer.

```
.table1{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

And when you create a table without that class, that table won't have a pointer when you hover over it.

So there i no need to use the :hover in this case.